# Windows Service closed when I disconnect one client socket

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, tcpclient

I have a server listened on a socket. This server is a Windows Service.

My problem is: When I disconnect a client `socket.Disconnect(false);` the service so closed and other clients are closed forcibly or new connections refused. I think that when service kill this client thread, the service not back to main thread.

Paste my code used for service (server functionality). Is correct the management of threads?

I run server with

```
this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipEnd);
this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
this.listenThread.Start();

private void ListenForClients()
{
  this.tcpListener.Start();

  while (true)
  {
    //blocks until a client has connected to the server
    TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

    //create a thread to handle communication
    //with connected client
    Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
    clientThread.Start(client);
  }
}

private void HandleClientComm(object client)
{
  TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
  NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

  byte[] message = new byte[4096];
  int bytesRead;

  while (true)
  {
    bytesRead = 0;

    try
    {
      //blocks until a client sends a message
      bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
    }
    catch
    {
      //a socket error has occured
      break;
    }

    if (bytesRead == 0)
    {
      //the client has disconnected from the server
      break;
    }

    //message has successfully been received
    ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
  }

  tcpClient.Close();
}
```

Sorry for my bad english and thanks for any suggestion

Comment: The service process exits? Do you see any exception or error detail in debugger / windows event log?

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems to be almost correct.
The only reason your app will crash is the line

```
NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
```

If you look at [the documentation for `GetStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream), you could see that it can throw InvalidOperationException if client is not connected. So in the situation when client connects and immediately disconnects it could be an issue.
So just guard this code with try-catch.

Also sometimes you might not get an explicit exception report, but have crash in multithreaded applications. To handle such exceptions subscribe to the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event.

Comment: But my client close socket correctly and the thread assigned to this client dont throw any exception. The problem is in the main thread who listen to the rest of clients. Main thread seems dead. The same code of server (service) moved to new application (Form) works perfectly. I understand that service is too much special with management threads. Isn´t it?

Comment: Actually services have nothing special with threads... At least i've converted one complex multithreaded desktop program to service once and there were no problems at all.